# I want retrieve data from database dynamically I wrote this code but i m getting error of index out of bound

Tags: android

I have write this code to get data dynamically form the data base but i m getting error of index out of bound for this please help me out where i m wrong please

Here is the error log also .....

```
 public ArrayList<String> displayEntery(String emailid) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ArrayList<String> retVals = new ArrayList<String>();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM LOGIN where EMAILID = '" + emailid
                    + "'";
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    // retVals.add(GetColumnValue(c, "NAME")); // name
                    String ugName = GetColumnValue(c, "NAME");
                    String email = GetColumnValue(c, "EMAILID");
                    String phone = GetColumnValue(c, "PHONE");
                    retVals.add(ugName);
                    retVals.add(email);
                    retVals.add(phone);

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            return retVals;

        }
```

LogCat:

```
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appetals.sqllite/com.appetals.sqllite.Welcomepage}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at com.appetals.sqllite.Welcomepage.onCreate(Welcomepage.java:41)
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-25 16:51:43.832: E/AndroidRuntime(4126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
```

Comment: What is GetColumnValue()?

Comment: Most likely you are trying to read a column that does not exist.

Comment: @theRoot ... why? which should be the advantage?

Comment: Change `if (c.moveToFirst()) {` to `if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {`

Answer (score -1):

Try..

```
 public ArrayList<String> displayEntery(String emailid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<String> retVals = new ArrayList<String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM LOGIN where EMAILID = '" + emailid
                + "'";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                // retVals.add(GetColumnValue(c, "NAME")); // name
                String ugName = GetColumnValue(c, "NAME");
                String email = GetColumnValue(c, "EMAILID");
                String phone = GetColumnValue(c, "PHONE");
                retVals.add(ugName);
                retVals.add(email);
                retVals.add(phone);

            } ;
        }
        return retVals;

    }
```

Comment: So, your answer is really to replace a `do...while` with a `while`?

Comment: hey thanks for the reply but it is not wrking same error i share the error log with here it is